# Calculate values of deep nested multi dimensional arrays in reverse

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures

I need to calculate reward for employees in my company.

I have this structure (for example):

[image]

And in PHP it represents the following array:

```
<?php

$structure = [
  "A" => [
    "B" => [
      "E" => [
        "M" => null
      ],
      "F" => [
        "N" => [
          "T" => null
        ],
        "O" => null
      ],
      "G" => [
        "P" => null,
        "Q" => [
          "U" => null,
          "V" => [
            "X" => null,
            "Y" => [
              "3" => [
                "4" => [
                  "4" => null,
                  "6" => null,
                  "7" => [
                    "8" => null
                  ],
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "Z" => null
          ]
        ]
      ],
      "H" => null
    ],
    "C" => [
      "I" => null,
      "J" => [
        "R" => null
      ],
      "K" => [
        "S" => [
          "W" => [
            "1" => null,
            "2" => null,
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "D" => [
      "L" => null
    ]
  ]
];
```

I need to calculate the reward for each employee. The end subordinates have reward only from their own work. But the seniors who have other subordinates have reward from their own work + works their subordinates.

For example:

Person **A** has own reward 10.
Person **D** has own reward 20.
Person **L** has own reward 15.

In the final,
Person **L** has final reward 15 (is final).
Person **D** has final reward 20 + 15 = 35 (D + L).
Person **A** has final reward 10 + 35 (A + D).

The calculation must be carried out below, however, the network can be arbitrarily deep. Calculating I would like to split into several parts. (For performance reasons)

1. The spider, which revises the structure to the appropriate format.
2. Calculate reward for each node.
3. Send information about each node via email.

I do not know how to proceed across the structure. Or to reorganize the structure to undergo easier. Can you think of anything?

I am grateful for you. Thanks!
@Martin

// EDIT: raw database

```
| id | parent | name
---------------------
| 1  | null   | Martin
| 2  | null   | Peter
| 3  | 1      | John
| 4  | 3      | Jack
```

// EDIT: new data structure:

```
[
  "A" => [
    "points" => 20,
    "childs" => [
      "B" => [
        "points" => 10,
        "childs" => [
          "C" => [
            "points" => 50,
            "childs" => null
          ]
        ]
      ],
      "D" => [
        "points" => 30,
        "childs" => [
          "4" => [
            "points" => 40,
            "childs" => null
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: look at some algorithms for graphs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: Do you have the starting reward for each of the 'last subordinates' ? E,g Persons L, M, O, P, R, T, X, Z, 1, 2, 5, 8 ?

Comment: I don't understand the reward distribution logic.

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres There is nothing what I need. I need to go from the bottom.

Comment: @JohnJoseph No, the starting reward must by calculated in the cycle.

Comment: @Strawberry The reward is calculated from the count of orders, their values and "events".

Comment: @mabezdek so whose rewards do you have to start with?

Comment: At the beginning I don't known reward. I have only employees structure. I need to calculate reward for each employees. But anyone who has children must be calculated after this children, because he inherits this rewards too. (he inherits rewards of his subordinates). Do you understand me now?

Comment: @mabezdek yes but you have to have some reward to start with otherwise how are you supposed to calculate with no rewards? you need to have the rewards for each of the 'bottom' employees in the structure (all the leaves in the branches). They have to inherit something so there must be a starting reward for example person L.

Comment: @JohnJoseph This is why I need to start from the bottom. I've yet calculate rewards for each of the 'bottom' employees. If the employee doesn't have children (is on the bottom), the reward is calculated only from this one employee (the count of orders etc).

Comment: @mabezdek yes so - the 'count of orders' do you have these values? that is what you need to start thee calculations with. I have answer but it is dependent on the bottom employees having rewards set. So as above do you have a reward value for Person L in your structure?

Comment: Yes, I can calculate this values. If I know which nodes are "on the bottom", I can calculate rewards for these bottom nodes. So answer: yes, I have this values.

Comment: OK, great. I'll post this answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by traversing through the structure recursively from the inside-out, and stores the rewards for each employee it can find in a flattened 2D array.

It is dependent on each leaf of the structure having a starting value, as it needs a base value to calculate back up the tree on.

Using RecursiveIteratorIterator with the CHILD_FIRST flag allows you to loop through the array 'backwards' which is what we want in this case as that is where the starting rewards are. As we go through the tree, we obtain the subordinates rewards, add it to the current employee, and continue .. so by the time we get back to the top of the structure, we have calculated all employees.

Storing the result in a flattened array is then much easier to use and manipulate further along your logic.

**Assumed starting structure:**

```
// Each leaf has a value (random for example sake)
$structure = [
"A" => [
    "B" => [
        "E" => [
            "M" => 10
        ],
        "F" => [
            "N" => [
                "T" => 15
            ],
            "O" => 5
        ],
        "G" => [
            "P" => 40,
            "Q" => [
                "U" => 30,
                "V" => [
                    "X" => 35,
                    "Y" => [
                        "3" => [
                            "4" => [
                                "5" => 5,
                                "6" => 10,
                                "7" => [
                                    "8" => 20
                                ],
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "Z" => 30
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "H" => 15
    ],
    "C" => [
        "I" => 25,
        "J" => [
            "R" => 25
        ],
        "K" => [
            "S" => [
                "W" => [
                    "1" => 40,
                    "2" => 50,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "D" => [
        "L" => 15
    ]
]
];
```

**Calculation:**

```
// Iterate through the structure from the outside-in (child/leaves first)
$data = new RecursiveArrayIterator($structure);
$dataIt = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($data, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
$rewards = [];
foreach ($dataIt as $value) {
    $subKeys = [];
    $rewards[$dataIt->key()] ?? $rewards[$dataIt->key()] = 0; // Suppress any undefined index errors
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $subKeys = array_keys($value);
        // traverse through all branches to obtain the existing reward values for subordinates
        array_walk_recursive($value, function($reward, $person) use (&$subKeys) {
            $subKeys[] = $person;
        });
        $subKeys = array_unique($subKeys);
        foreach ($subKeys as $employee) {
            $rewards[$dataIt->key()] += $rewards[$employee];
        }
    } else {
        $rewards[$dataIt->key()] += $value;
    }
}
print_r($rewards);
```

**Return/final array:**

```
Array
(
[M] => 10
[E] => 10
[T] => 15
[N] => 15
[O] => 5
[F] => 35
[P] => 40
[U] => 30
[X] => 35
[4] => 60
[6] => 10
[8] => 20
[7] => 20
[3] => 90
[Y] => 180
[Z] => 30
[V] => 335
[Q] => 520
[G] => 745
[H] => 15
[B] => 1060
[I] => 25
[R] => 25
[J] => 25
[1] => 40
[2] => 50
[W] => 90
[S] => 180
[K] => 270
[C] => 435
[L] => 15
[D] => 15
[A] => 1935
)
```

To get the number of employees under each node, you can do that easily in one line using `count`:

```
$employeesPersonA = count($structure['A'], COUNT_RECURSIVE); // 33
$employeesPersonC = count($structure['A']['C'], COUNT_RECURSIVE); // 8
$employeesPersonK = count($structure['A']['C']['K'], COUNT_RECURSIVE); // 4
```

EDIT:
For your database structure, you cannot get a multi dimensional result set out of the database so your only option there is to go through the result set and build your structure in PHP from that.

Comment: Nice, it looks very nice :) Please, one other thing. I need to known count of direct descendants for each nodes. Can you add it to your example? And one performance questions: I need to do very much iterations over sql results to get "input" structure. Can you think of better solution for this? I will post database structure in my first post.

Comment: Added on top. :) Thanks!

Comment: Added count for direct descendants to my answer. For the database / SQL, ask a separate question with SQL tags for that.

Comment: The code already has comments - what in particular detail do you want? Added extra detail at the top of the answer.

Comment: I need to calculate from child (as you have) and I need to sum this with one another value (obtained from the database based on emyploee ID).

Comment: That should be very easy to do, but it isn't part of your original question. If you still can't work out how to do that post another question with code of what you have tried.

Comment: I edited my post, because I don't wont to create duplicate topic. I updated data structure, can I go trough this array with this solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example, simplified to consider only nodes, 'A','B','C',D', & 'L'...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(user CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,lft INT NOT NULL
,rgt INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('A',1,10),
('B',2,3),
('C',4,5),
('D',6,9),
('L',7,8);

SELECT y.user
     , GROUP_CONCAT(x.user ORDER BY x.lft) nodes
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON x.lft BETWEEN y.lft AND y.rgt
 GROUP 
    BY y.user
 ORDER 
    BY y.lft;

+------+-----------+
| user | nodes     |
+------+-----------+
| A    | A,B,C,D,L |
| B    | B         |
| C    | C         |
| D    | D,L       |
| L    | L         |
+------+-----------+
```

Comment: What represents lft and rgt column? If I understand correctly, that I get for each user his childrens (with this example). But how I can order it? I mean: user A is on first row, but for calculating reward is needed child B. But node B is not calculated yet (it is on second row). Do you understand me? I need to have calculated node L to calculate D. I need to have calculated B, C, D, L to calculated A.